# Xbox 360 freezes at startup screen, audio still works, input does not

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

My wife and I have two xbox 360s, and recently hers (which is also the oldest) started doing some strange video glitching.  I have a dlna server set up in our house, and two days ago, while watching a movie through our dlna server to her xbox, the video simply froze.  The audio continued to work, and we could hear our controller input working (pressing the jewel resulted in the proper noise, etc.).  Let me be clear, the video froze, it did not go black.  We just figured part of the xbox software froze, restarted the xbox, and it worked fine.

The next day, same issue happened while watching something over dlna, however, this time, restarting the xbox did not work.

Now, when I boot the xbox, the video freezes after a few seconds of the startup splash screen.  It goes through all the audio/music of the boot up process, however, the controller is unresponsive (pressing buttons/joysticks does not result in any audio).

I've done a few troubleshooting steps:

1. Unplugged everything from the xbox (including usb wireless, a usb stick, hard drive, power, and video), and replugged in only the power and video cable.
2. Started the xbox from a wired controller, while holding the Y and Right Trigger buttons, which some forum posts suggested would reset the video settings.
3. Used the same power and av cables with our other xbox on the same tv to see if it were an issue with the cables.
4. Attempted to boot up an xbox 360 update as [described on the xbox.com update page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/system-updates-info?icid=furl_update#020243a567a54c93b2619e448e678e6f)
5. Opened the xbox, and used canned air to clear out any dust from the inputs, heat sinks, and components.  I also checked all the capacitors for any bulking or leaks, and everything looks fine.
6. Used the same tv and cables with a second xbox 360, and everything works correctly.

None of these have resolved our issue.  Coming from a software developer background, this doesn't really look like hardware failure, only because it is both displaying some video and audio, and I'm more thinking it's some sort of software problem that we triggered.

For some background, we've been using my dlna server for about 6 months now, and had no problem until now, so I'm not 100% sure the streaming caused the bug, it's just what we have been using that xbox for recently, so it's just happenstance.  We've used the other xbox for streaming, too, and haven't had any issues.

This is also a first generation xbox 360 (from 2006), so it does not support HDMI, and it is indeed old.

Has anyone else encountered this video freeze and unresponsive controls on startup, or while using the system video player?  Any suggestions for a fix?

**Edit:** Here is an image of how far it gets in the splash screen (taken with my phone):

[image: The furthest my xbox 360 gets in the splash screen animation]

Comment: Nice troubleshooting. Try clearing the cache(might be a corrupt update file) of the HDD. Try it without the HDD. Vaccuum the network port. Have you tried a different network cable. Are more than one Xbox or P.C on? I suggest redownloading the optional media update. Please try it with the disk tray open and no usb extras.

Comment: Try dropping your screen resolution.(both Xbox HDMI?)

Comment: I have tried booting with the hard drive detached, and this also did not fix it.

Also, I cannot boot the system far enough to try changing the resolution, or do any sort of system updates, and I thought I made that pretty clear.

Comment: You did. Have you tried it with the disk tray ejected?If you want to try an update, you can download the update files from Xbox.com, install them to a disk or USB and load them.Is it HDMI or Component cables. I find with my 7 or so Xbox, that issues like this are either Hardware(dust/failing components), too much power coming from the Xbox, ie. USB, plug & play, disk reading in the drive.Or...Loose Component cables(ie. works with standard, not the high definition switch on the component cable. Try to leave the Xbox on for 10 minutes. And when you return turn on controller. Remove battery pack.

Comment: I find that can jolt the Xbox to load what's on screen when freezing.

Comment: Tried booting with the disk tray open, no affect.  I'll see if i can sort out the xbox update for usb, and get back to you on that.

Comment: The xbox does not boot from the system update from [xbox.com's update page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/system-updates-info?icid=furl_update#020243a567a54c93b2619e448e678e6f)

Comment: Harsh. I would be vaccuuming the Xbox. And considering that the power pack(I know you tried the other one) may be a factor. I would try the Y + Left trigger again. Looks high definition there. Component?

Comment: Yeah, HD Component.  My wife bought it a few years ago - it looks like it has some generic hooks for xbox 360, playstation 3, and possibly wii - I tried using it (along with the power cord of the failing xbox) with my newer xbox, and everything works fine.

Booting while holding Y + Left Trigger still has no affect.

Comment: I have some canned air, so I will try opening it up tomorrow and making sure everything is cleaned out.  While the xbox is running, it doesn't seem to be running any hotter than my newer xbox, so I'm not sure if it's an airflow issue, but if it's dust, hopefully I'll get that taken care of.  I'll post an update tomorrow once I get a chance.

Comment: Sorry I realise I've benn reading this main page and three others very similar. Didn't mean to overlook the HDMI. Yes, you were clear. So component cables, have you tried just RCA Looks like you did) just to be sure though.

Comment: I just realised, on my friend's t.v. Xbox works fine on one channel. Not the other. Could be the t.v.

Comment: Just finished opening it up, blew some canned air into it, it wasn't particularly dusty, but i cleaned out the heat sinks, fans, and all the ports.  Still the same issue.

Also, we've been using the same cables and tv for the other xbox, and there are no issues.  Not sure what you mean by channel, since it's a static input on the back of the tv.

Comment: Try a different AV or Component channel.

Comment: Have you turned it on without a controller?

Comment: Sounds silly. Turn it on without the cables. Get your 4 red lights to tell you it's not plugged in. Then try again. Sucks. And also, I figure it may be the cable port. Not really reccomended, though I have an Xbox, I have to move the cable for it to progress.

Comment: I had already tried booting without the av cable to get a red ring, in hopes that it would just start some mechanism.  I've also tried booting the system without a controller.  Neither worked.  I didn't bother with a second cable, simply because the same cable connected to the same tv with a different xbox worked, and the cable had previously worked for months on the xbox.

Comment: Yeah. Last thing I've been trying(replicating). Take the HDD off.

Comment: Try swapping the HDD's?

Comment: Try overloading it with a game, USB, and HDD.

Comment: I've already tried (but didn't note) using the hard drive from my other xbox.  The failing xbox had very little hard drive space, so I had been testing on and off with a usb flash drive.  The first few attempts had a game in the drive, with the flash drive, and I had no success then.  I'll try again once I reassemble the xbox, just to be sure, but I don't have particularly high hopes.

Comment: Try a different power pack if you are confident.

Comment: Try a usb only in the other Xbox, update, change to the frozen Xbox(usb only) to see if it was from an update.

Comment: I've still been looking into this and the most logical account that I have heard is that the biggest issue with screen freezing on P.C type products is memory being loose. Now, I'm not sure on the 360, though consider if there is a memory slot in the 360(not to my knowledge) reslotting it would solve this. Point I'm eventuating to is that even though there's probably not a slot, something could be loose. Worth a shot if you throw it across the room and it breaks open.

Comment: This was crossing my mind this week with a failing 250GB HDD, with data transferred from a 120GB, in an arcade(normally no HDD)Xbox. Corrupting files after it passed 120GB.

Comment: I fixed it to a degree using a transfer cable and a 20GB HDD to read the stuff quicker. Along with a USB to update. Wanted to comment, just checked the page and it's current again, so see if it helps. I'll be looking into shortcut commands on bootup, to look for ways to clear the update or corrupted files. Have fun then.

Comment: So re reading... Could you delete the most recent things downloaded and scroll through to the end of the games in the HDD to find any corrupt or incomplete files and delete them, along with any LIVE profiles(just profile, not profile and items.)

Comment: To delete them, put the HDD in the other Xbox or use a transfer type cable.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is four years old but maybe it will help others.

When the Xbox360 starts to get graphical glitches like that where it sounds as though everything is still working and it is only the  video that is affected, the culprit is a chip on the mainboard which is experiencing a bad solder connection. This is NOT like the regular RROD that is caused by the chips under the heat sinks; this chip is much smaller and is usually located somewhere near the video cable plug.
Additionally, it is easy to test to see if it is this chip; just turn on your xbox360 with the case open and push down on the chip with your finger. If the glitches are affected when you press, this chip is the problem.
You can easily fix this chip using a hot air gun and some tin foil to shield the rest of the xbox. Keep the gun on the chip, moving in tiny circles, until the solder is melted. (30sec-1min?). Let it cool, then see what happens when you boot. Should be fixed.
This is ONLY applicable when the video output seems to be the only thing affected, as in your case.
Sorry I do not have a chip name or pictures. I'm just writing this off the top of my head and since the question IS 4 years old no body would probably want them anyways. :)

Comment: I don't mind marking this as accepted, but I do think it does need a proper chip name and potentially a picture, otherwise this won't help anyone else that runs into this same issue.

Comment: This answer mentions a faulty chip. It's called the HANA chip, it's responsible for HDMI out.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever an XBOX 360 starts to freeze upon bootup or within just a few minutes of gameplay it is usually an indicator that your unit is about to get the dreaded Red Rings Of Death (A.K.A. - "RROD"). We've repaired many systems for this issue.

We highly recommending seeking out a reliable game repair shop that offers a reball service with a good warranty. Always ask to see that machine the shop will be using to repair your XBOX 360. If all they have is a heat gun of some sorts, i highly recommend that you don't choose to get the repair performed at that shop.

Comment: My hesitation with this is I'm the kind of person who would rather fix it myself.  Not that I don't trust repair shops, but hourly repair mixed with trial and error doesn't sit well with me.

Answer (score -1):

I had a launch 360, and it started doing the same thing in 2011.  It took about 4-5 months to go through the entire process you've described, and no amount of compressed air, or any other troubleshooting could save it.  I would compare the cost of reball service with the cost of replacing it, and go with whichever seems more advantageous to your needs.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, it's just advice, it should be put into a comment above.

Answer (score -1):

My xxbox 360 started doings those things just before the Red Rings Of Death (RROF) apeared. I suggest you (if your xbox360 still has warranty) to call to the microsoft offices so the can change your xbox, that was what i did.
Later it happened again and i had no warranty anymore, so i took my xbox to a hardware shop so they could fix it, that can be the best alternative.
There's a do-it-yourself alternative: Unplug everything except from the power cable, cover the fan with chopsticks, wrap your xbox arround a hot blanket and turn it on, 15 mins should do it. Have luck!

Comment: Same as the above answer. This should be a comment. It's not an answer to his question cause it doesn't resolve anything.

Answer (score -1):

maybe your issieu is solved but maybe not i had the same proplem and i stil own my original first first xbox 360 there is two thing that seemed to do the trick for me 
first and easyest your video input cable should have 6 cables now if this is the case simply switch the litl button switch on the cable to hd or hdmi, power on the xbox, you wont have any video at all, while the console is on switch the cable back to the original stance, the console should restard and it should have worked but its only temporary

seccond the best thing to do strip the plastic find a link on youtube how to do it and only ceep the iron of the console itself it gives the console a huge life boost since it will never go hot again you only hear the cd tray spin the console self is mouse quiet do not remove the white plastic going from your fann to the big iron block it needs the cooling airflow from the fan 
!!!ATTENTION!!! 
pay attention when removing the plastic do not force it off you will break it.
unplug your powwer source when removing the plastic.
when you rewire your power source USE HANDGLOVES!!! chance of an electrick shock when touching the metal casing 9 out of 10 you will get shocked!!!
do not touch the consoles heat pack thing the big mettal block in the middle of the console can get up to 60 to 80 degrees celcius
and under all circomstances do not let children power to console on or of at the console itself use a controller same for switching disks chance of electric shock when touching the metal xbox casing

if your console still freezes and you stripped the console look at the cd tray there is two cables carefully lift your cd tray and see if both cables are still attachen to be shure give them a gentle push do dot force it you will either brake your cable the cd tray or worse you snapep your giant green print plate in half so do not use to much force.

another trick wich i do not reccomend have not tested it myself its hear say from my brother put it in your fridge for five to ten mins so all the oil and fluids in the console can cool down making the moniculles take their original positions then when the console is cold but not MOIST OR WET plug it in and it could work YET AGAIN A WARNING!!! i have never tested this myself its only hearsay from my brother i do not reccomend this methot at all

!!!DISCLAIMER!!!
i do not have expert knowledge of electronics or programming or any other electricity actions i am not a repair centre i only advice what you could do im not sayying it a magic fix for me it worked and on my friends console two i do not take any responcebility for broken divices only use my advice if you know what you are doing or if you want to give it a go and last but not least my native language is dutch so my apollogies for my english

Comment: Please do not use LOLCAT language. Thank you.